# Android get certificate of server before doing request

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate, httpclient

I have "Https" connection with my web service.

On Android and ios how can I get the certificate "public key" of server before doing request?

I don't want to add the certificate to my assets folder or on my project.

Comment: You mean how to get the CRT file before doing the request? Can't you embed that certificate in your app?

Comment: yes i want the CRT, yes i can't embed the certificate in my application

Comment: I guess then you could use OpenSSL for Android to mimic `openssl s_client -connect HOST:PORTNUMBER | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'`

Comment: kindly can you describe more, also is this doable from code ?

Comment: You can try key chaining concept. By following this concept based ,on some predefined parameters you can authorize the server and on authorizing you can fetch the public key of server.

Comment: you mean i have to override the methods in TrustManager ?